# Set Probability With SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following:

```
    Number   Occurrence
     1         12
     2         30
     3         15
     4         20
```

I want to calculate the probability according to each number's occurrence and then want to get the number with highest probability.

I would like the SQL query for this.

Comment: If just highest probability isn't this just the highest occurance and you don't need the probability

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?  Do you just want the number with the highest occurrence, or do you actually want to 'roll the dice' and get a random value weighted by the occurrence?

Comment: I want to work with probability , I need probability to assign individual with individual probability . SO not only column with Highest Probability ,I actually need all columns with different probability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Number, Occurance, 
       Occurance*1.0/(SELECT SUM(Occurance) FROM YourTable) AS Probability
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY Occurance DESC
```

Comment: why `*1.0` please - is it to get 1 decimal place?

Comment: Ok that what I think,I should give more idea.Occurance is already aggregate function. I mean  Occurance is count of another column.

Comment: @BarryKaye If Occurance is an INT then the operation will implicitly return an INT datatype and all the values would be 0. The `*1.0` forces a non-integer return type.

Answer (score 1):

TSQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1) Number
FROM Table_name
ORDER BY Occurance DESC
```

MySql:

```
SELECT Number
FROM Table_name
ORDER BY Occurance DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: And why you assume it's for SQL-Server?